# how to get the id of element from which previous event is triggered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In jquery i can get the id of element which is triggered an event very easily. is there anyway in jquery to get the id of element which is triggered an event just before last event? i have a table with many row on clicking each row an event is triggered. i wan to get the id of the element which is triggered just before new event.

Answer (score 2):

Each event just do this:

```
window.last_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

And then on the next event you can access `window.last_id` :)

Before trying to use `window.last_id`, first make sure it is not `undefined`!

```
if (window.last_id) {
    // you can use it
}
else {
    // you cannot, it is undefined, this must be the first event called
}
```